# Obscure issue, Google AdMob SDK, XCode 8.2 + Cocoapods integration

Tags: swift, cocoapods, google-ima, admob, xcode8.2

I have come across a really strange issue that has kept me busy for over a week which i believe to be a bug with the GoogleAdMob SDK, Xcode 8.2, cocoapods or a combination of those.

I am posting it here, in hopes an engineer can confirm the bug and point our team in the right direction to resolution.

The problem goes like this:

1. Create an empty Xcode project
2. Add/Install `GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob` pod
3. Commit everything and delete the repository from local machine
4. Check out repository again
5. Hit Build. Project will fail to build with error `ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds`
6. To fix, comment out the `GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob` pod and run `pod update`, then uncomment it again and run `pod update` again, project will build.
7. If you try to commit at this point, git will pick up no changes
8. Repeat steps 3 and 4, and you will be back at step 5

I have created a repository here https://github.com/piterwilson/testAdmob where the bug can be reproduced.

The 'fix' that i have found will not work for our team as we commit our code and send it to a Jenkins server that creates a lot of builds with different code signatures required by our business.

The Jenkins build always fails with ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds

Extra information : This has only happened starting this year. Maybe because of Xcode 8.2 (?) but we can't be sure where the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a PR that resolves the issue in a reliable manner: https://github.com/piterwilson/testAdmob/pull/1

The repository was missing the GoogleAdMobs binary. It's a rather large file (38M), so perhaps the submitter of the question has some local configuration that automatically ignores large files? The binary should have been in this commit: https://github.com/piterwilson/testAdmob/commit/a0834a4d2f2b82da98add1bc3c49d8c0c28ffd86 (at least that's when it appeared for me when I tried to reproduce the issue.)